# In database, can I insert a "virtual row" in one table that points to a row in another table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm newbie in database, not sure if it's a basic question.

Suppose I have two tables of same type. Each has a few rows as below:

```
table1:
row1
row2

table2:
row3
row4
```

can I insert a `vrow3` into table1 like:

```
table1:
row1
row2
vrow3  // -> table2.row3

table2:
row3
row4
```

where `vrow3` is like a pointer in C that points to the `row3` in table2, its content always refers to the content of `row3` in table2, no matter how `row3` is updated.

Is there something like this?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a "Virtual row" in databases. Tell us what is that you are trying to achieve, there would be alternate approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you need is called a “view”. It is a “query with a name”: you can use it like a table in `SELECT` statements, but it is replaced by its definition.

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE /* condition that specifies which rows */
```

So when the data in `table2` change, that change is immediately reflected in the view.